# Django Admin: Custom Inline Model FormSet (with non foreign-key relationship)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

(django 1.2.4)

I have two different unrelated (there is no foreign key relationship between them) django models. 
For example, let's say: 'School' and 'Teacher'.

What I need is that, when I open add/edit view in django admin interface for 'School' object to have inline formset of Teacher objects. Obiously this won't be FK relationship, but rather logical relationship (example: teachers that are in same country as school...).

Form I need to display is standard model form. 
I have a function that would give me list (queryset if needed) of teachers for given school.

Is it possible to implement something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactlly solution for my problem, but I ended up inheriting ModelAdmin class and overriding change_view method, implementing functionality I needed (retrieving objects I need and passing them through context to change_form template, which I also extended).

... and ended up really liking Django AdminSite extensibility

Comment: Is there any chance you could share an example? I have a very similar need and would love to take a look at some relevant code, particularly the part where you handle the POST info.

Comment: for this particular solution I needed only readonly views od related objects, so don't have POST code...

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtful that there is a legitimate reason for doing this. For example, it is most logical for Teacher to have a foreign key to School. However, I recently solved this problem, and subsequently realized it wasn't a good idea after all. Since sometimes it just takes seeing it expressed to think of better solutions, I provide the solution:

The problem you get into putting non-related models as inlines is the parent_model is all wrong. In this case, the parent_model is School, which is incorrect and causes an exception. Assuming Teacher has a real parent, the solution is to correct the parent_model field in your InlineModelAdmin subclass. You can do so by overriding the init func:

```
class TeacherInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
        # override to permit change parent_model from School to Teacher-Parent
        # Assume Teacher's parent is Employer
        super(TeacherInline, self).__init__(Employer, admin_site)
```

Comment: Seems that this solution does not work any more with Django 1.7. System checks framework doesn't even allow to start the webserver and complains on the foreign key.